# GSON how transform next json to Java with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, gson

How Tranform next JSON

```
{
 "objectIdFieldName": "OBJECTID",
 "features": [
  {
   "attributes": {
    "STOP_ID": "10",
    "STOP_NAME": "KR 19 - CL 70",
    "STOP_LAT": 4.6582586500000005,
    "STOP_LON": -74.065565919999997
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

to object Java for GSON actually I have

```
public class GsonParaderosSincroniza {

    public GsonParaderosAttributes[] features;

    public GsonParaderosSincroniza() {

    }
}

public class GsonParaderosAttributes {
    public GsonParaderos attributes;

    public GsonParaderosAttributes(){

    }
}

public class GsonParaderos {
    @SerializedName("STOP_ID")
    public String sTOP_ID;
    @SerializedName("STOP_NAME")
    public String sTOP_NAME;
    @SerializedName("STOP_LAT")
    public double sTOP_LAT;
    @SerializedName("STOP_LON")
    public double sTOP_LON;

    public GsonParaderos() {

    }
}
```

but exit this error

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 10 column 1
```

Comment: can you add your serialization code?

Comment: I just tried out the code with your classes and the JSON you posted just by using `gson.toJson(...)`, and it worked just fine. Are you sure you are passing in the JSON that you posted? The error message suggests that there is the beginning of a String at column 1 of line 10, which is not the case in your example JSON.